# String.Index does not have a member named advancedBy

Tags: swift

This is the swift code I have as an exercise from my class, I am re-writing it(as I am new to it).

At the position of 
`let end = starIndex.advancedBy(position)`, I am getting an error message of `String.Index` does not have a member named `advancedBy` I am not sure what this means or how to correct it just yet, many thanks for any help in understanding what I am doing wrong.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var str : String = "Hello, playground"

str

let strFix = " Can not change"
str = "Good bye"
//strFix = "Testing"

var str2 = str + "F"

var townName = "NeverLand"

let population = 30000

let numOfStopLight : Int = 10

print("\(townName) has populations of \(population) 
and has \   (numOfStopLight) Stop Lights")

for c in townName.unicodeScalars
{
    print ("\(c)")
}

let starIndex = str.startIndex

let position = 3

let end = starIndex.advancedBy(position)

let charAt = str[end]

let range = starIndex...end

str[range]

let aChar: Character = "\u{1F60E}"

str.append(aChar)

let dollarSign = "\u{24}"       //$, Unicode scalar U+0024
let blackHeart = "\u{2665}"     //  , Unicode scalar U+2665
let sparklingHeart = "\u{1F496}" //  , Unicod scalar U=1F496
str.append(Character(sparklingHeart))

for c in str.characters
{
    print("\(c)")

}
    for c in str.unicodeScalars
{
    print("\(c.value)")
}

/////////////////////


struct Car
{
   var make : String = ""
   var price : Double = 0.0
   let color : String = "RED"

    func getMske()->String
    {
       return make
    }
    mutating func setMake (m: String)
    {
        make = m
    }
     func showCar()->String
    {
        return "Make:\(make) Price=\(price) Color= \(color)"

    }
 }
  //let us make some Car

  var myCar = Car(make: "Nissan", price: 45000.0)

  print(myCar.showCar())

  myCar.setMake("Nissan2016")

  print (myCar.showCar())

  //show pass value

    func doChange (var c: Car)
    {
     c.setMake("Toyota")

    print (c.showCar())


    }

doChange(myCar)
print (myCar.showCar())


//let us have a class

class Xcar
{
    var make :String = ""
    var price : Double = 0.0
    var color : String = ""

    init(m :String, p: Double, c: String)
    {
        self.make = m
        self.price = p
        self.color = c
    }
    func setMake(m: String)
    {
        self.make = m

    }
    func showXCar()->String
    {

        return "Make: \(make) Price=\(price) Color=\(color)"
    }
}
 func doChangex( c:Xcar)
{
   c.setMake("BMW")
    print("\(c.showXCar())")

}
var hisCar = Xcar(m: "Fiat", p: 15000.0, c: "Blue")
print ("\(hisCar.showXCar())")

doChangex(hisCar)
//notice the function did change
//because it was a class
print ("\(hisCar.showXCar())")
//What is optional

let a: Float?
let b: Float?
let c :Float?

a = 10
b = 20
c = 5

//this is implicit unrap
let ave = (a! + b! + c!)/3.0

if let x = a, y = b, z = c
{
    print ("\((x + y + z) / 3.0)")

}
else
{
    print ("missing value...")



}


// note Array, Double, Float, Int and Dictionary are all struct

var intArray = [Int] ()
intArray.append(50)
intArray.append(100)
intArray.append(600)
intArray.maxElement()
intArray.capacity
intArray.count
intArray.description
intArray.dropFirst()
intArray.first
intArray.description
intArray.removeFirst()
intArray.description

for c in intArray
{
   print("\(c)")

}


var dict = [Int :String ] ()

dict = [235 :"Jack", 100: "Joe", 60: "Lisa"]
dict.description

for(key, value) in dict
{
    print ("\(key)")

}

var name = dict[235]
```

Comment: You should give your question a title that has to do with the question, not with "that you have a problem". Just a small tip ;)

Comment: please revise your title and read [ask]

Comment: That is a good idea! Thank you for the tip. I will take it to heart when posting other questions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it in one line

```
let startIndex = str.startIndex.advancedBy(3)
```

Comment: I really like how that is written thank you! I will let you know how it works out.

Comment: You're welcome. And just for you to know - if you liked an answer you can upvote it, and if you got an right answer (Jay's answer) you should also mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

The code has a number of issues and we don't know what the expected output is, but here are a few items:

The line with just 'str' on it should be removed.

You may be running an older version of Xcode or OS (or both). This is Swift2 and you should be using Xcode 7 or higher.

Also, there are 'var' that should be 'let' (hisCar) and there are a number of unused variables.

The good news is once you fix the issues that, the code runs correctly (as far as I can tell)

Comment: Thank you! You are correct- once I was able to get to an updated version of Xcode the errors went away. Many many thanks for replying!